# Drupal Filter not working in views?

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to filter a development profile in a view where it only shows the developers of the project. I have the filter set on published and only with taxonomy terms "Developers", but the view keeps displaying literally everything published, as if its ignoring the taxonomy filter.

Has anyone ran into this problem and know how to fix it? I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: Are the developers authenticated users on your site?

Comment: It is a little bit unclear exactly what you currently have.  Could you go into a bit of detail about how your taxonomy is set up, how it is associated with the content you are using as the base (contextual filter?), and what specific filter you are using?  I tested a view that has a term reference field called area.  The `Content: Has taxonomy term` filter worked just fine with that setup.

Answer (score 0):

[Maybe you can add role. Admin menu --> People ---> Permissions --> Roles](https://www.drupal.org/node/120614)

example : "Editor" created

At the views's filter criteria choose: Show campaign for specific roles (field_bcc_specific_user_roles) and select Is equal to "Editor"